# How to select the text from my textbox inside a repeater using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater and inside of it is a textbox that contains my data from the database. 
Of course at run-time it will generate lots of data meaning lots of textboxes too.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpter" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <asp:Label ID="lblLegend" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.Name")%>' Font-Bold="true" />
      </legend>
      <div style="border: single, 1px;">
        <div>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.Message")%>' Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
       <div>
         <asp:Button ID="btnCopy" runat="server" Text="Copy" CommandName="Copy" OnClientClick="copyClipboard()" />
         </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

What I want is to select the text from the textbox besides the copy button  when I clicked the button so that I can copy it on clipboard..

```
function copyClipboard() {
    CopiedTxt = document.selection.createRange();
    CopiedTxt.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

Comment: Please can you post the relevant html generated by the repeater, otherwise we only have half the information to work with.

Comment: I couldnt add my code on my question above. How Can I add it?

Comment: Just copy code snippets from your Visual Studio solution and paste it in your question, i. e. "edit" your question...

Comment: Be sure to read this question and answer: [how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to edit your ASP code and add **CssClass="txtMessage"** to the *TextBox*.
Also *CssClass="btnCopy"* to the *Button*
And removed the **OnClientClick="copyClipboard()"** because we will handle that in our jQuery as below:

ASP:-

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpter" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
        <asp:Label ID="lblLegend" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.Name")%>' Font-Bold="true" />
        </legend>
        <div style="border: single, 1px;">
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" CssClass="txtMessage" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.Message")%>' Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:Button ID="btnCopy" runat="server" CssClass="btnCopy" Text="Copy" CommandName="Copy" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Don't forget to include jQuery library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

And the jQuery will handle all clicks to any item with class of **btnCopy** and look for **.txtMessage** item inside the **parent of the parent** of the **button**
And select the text inside that **TextBox**
And return false so your click won't take you any where...

jQuery:-

```
$(function () {
    $(".btnCopy").click(function (e) {
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".txtMessage").select();
        return false;
    });
});
```

I wish that will work for you and this is the screenshot:
http://i59.tinypic.com/5ujvc9.jpg
http://i62.tinypic.com/35d4y7l.jpg

Good luck ;)

Comment: What do you get: Page refresh. Or what have you included the jquery library. Are the onclientclick there, remove it. Do you want me to post a screenshot with the full code.

Comment: Can you send me the screenshot on my email? I couldnt open it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass `this` to your function `copyClipboard`.
so your button code will look like this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCopy" runat="server" Text="Copy" OnClientClick="copyClipboard(this)"/>
```

and a class to your div wrapping your textbox,

```
<div class="texdiv">
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.Message")%>' Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

and your `js` function would be

```
function copyClipboard(th) {
            alert($(th).parents().prevAll('.texdiv').find('*[id^=rpter_txtMessage]').val());
        }
```

on client click of button, you need to find it's previous textbox then you can get it's value
it will give you corresponding `textbox` value

Comment: I tried it but still the same. Actually what  I really want to do is to click the button and the text from the textbox will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $(".copybtn").click (function (e) {
        Var txtMsgVal = $(this).parent().parent().find(".txtMsg").text();
        // Do something with the txtMsgVal here
        alert(txtMsgVal);
    });
});
```

You just need a class attribute on both the button and the input (the message).

Note: I have used jQuery in this answer so you have to include the jQuery library in your source code.

Good luck ;)

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but I tried to alert the txtMsgVal but I get undefined value.

Comment: actually what I really want to do is to focus and select the text on the textbox so that  I can copy it.

Comment: @Chinx I have edited the answer. You get an undefined value because the DOM is not ready. Try it now. I am looking to hear forward from you ;)

Comment: @Chinx your iD must be unique. Is the ID attribute in your source code will be in html (i.e.: <button id="btnCopy">copy </button>)

Comment: If so your page must contain just one (unique) ID. (You musn't use repeator). If you want to use a repeator my code must target the class. ;)

Comment: yup my ID attribute in my source code is in html. I still get undefined. I have to use a repeater because I'am loading multplie data.

Comment: So can you add class="copybtn" to your button and class="textMsg" to the message input. And I will edit my aswer to match.

Comment: Now when you click on the button the val of the message is returned as an alert message

Comment: the alert message is empty.

Comment: Can you please give me the generated html and I promise that I will give you the solution ;)

Comment: what do you mean by generated html?

Comment: I mean open your page in browser press ctrl+u the html code is sitting there select it all and post it here

Comment: Can I email it? Gve me ur email add.

Comment: I am really want to help you because you are very interested in coding ;)

Comment: @Chinx Look at the other answer I shared